Is it possible to have a system that show superconducting behavior in magnetization and insulating behavior in resistivity?
Is it possible to have a system that show superconducting behavior in magnetization measurements and insulating behavior in resistivity measurements? if yes then please provide some references? In other words, does the requirement of bulk superconductivity is via Meissner effect or via resistance or both needed simultaneously?
